# Calculating electrical resistivity of a material

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, material-science

If I plan to measure the resistivity of a high resistivity material, would it not make sense to alter the geometry of the sensor to make A/l as small as possible and reduce the voltage to get a low resistance value to reduce the resistivity measured at conditions which are easy to fulfill experimentally. Because i'm a bit confused as i'm being told to increase the voltage and make sure A/l is large to measure the resistivity of this material. Thanks in advance for any help.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do the experiment typically you will apply some known voltage $V$ and measure the current $I$. This is given by:

$$ I = \frac{V}{R} = \frac{V}{\rho} \frac{A}{\ell} $$

Your problem is that if the resitivity, $\rho$, is very high then $V/\rho$ will be very small and the current $I$ will be too small to measure accurately. If so you can increase the current back to measurable levels by increasing the value of $A/\ell$.

Comment: Further, if the cross sectional area is too small your measured resistivity may be dominated by surface scattering, so you won't get an accurate measurement of the intrinsic material resistivity. This is often a problem in thin film measurements of low resistivity materials (e.g. copper in my experience), compounded by slight variations in film thickness.

Comment: to add to the answer of @John Rennie: the lowest dc currents that can be measured with the best (room-temperature) amplifiers today is about 10 fA, if the measurement bandwidth is 1 Hz. These amplifiers are based on commercial operational amplifiers with external circuitry comprising a negative feedback, which gives an I-V converter, whose conversion ratio is given by the feedback resistor.

Comment: @JonCuster the material i'm trying to measure is a liquid, sorry didn't make that clear. I'm assuming that the surface scattering problem doesn't apply in that case.

Comment: @flaudemus yh we'll be using AC current to avoid charge accumulation at the electrodes which apparantly causes errors.

Comment: @J.Doe - if it has a surface, there is additional scattering. This is particularly important if one of the transverse dimensions is on the order of, or smaller than, the mean free path.

Comment: @John Rennie Just to confirm, a high voltage is also ideal in this case right?

Comment: @J.Doe It is probably wise to use a four-point method (separate contacts for supplying current and for sensing the voltage drop).

Comment: @Pieter yh but online, according to info packs provided by companies that sell these sensors, they say using 2 electrodes is more suited for measuring high resistivity than 4 electrodes, not exactly sure about the reason why though.

Comment: @J.Doe It is easier to have two electrodes. But your application is some liquid, and one might worry about effects of electrolysis at the current terminals. Look at articles in the literature to see how others dealt with similar substances.

Comment: @Pieter thanks for the tips. I'm afraid there's like nothing about the electrolysis on the liquid (r134a) i could find online or even from the property specifications of the liquid provided to me by the company producing the liquid which is sponsoring my phd on this lol.

Comment: @Pieter dont think there are any electrolyis effects on it, since there's no literature about it and since we'll be using a high liquid purity in vacuum conditions.

Comment: @J.Doe That is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1,1,1,2-Tetrafluoroethane ! Maybe you could compare with measurements on for example transformer oil or molten sulphur. I have no experience with that kind of really insulating liquids, but "guard electrodes" might be useful.

Comment: @Pieter yh comparing it with those liquids sounds like a really good idea, thanks a lot. will look into "guard electrodes" too, thanks.

Comment: @J.Doe: the I-V converters that I mentioned would also work (with the same current resolution) at low ac frequencies, typically up to a few hundred Hertz. However, you have to take care that your cable capacitances do not allow for significant ac currents parallel to your high resistor. Four-terminal measurements are always a good idea.

Comment: @flaudemus i read that cable capacitance is only an issue with high frequency ac, i'm gonna be using low frequencies so i dont think it should be a problem, correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: This is a question of numbers. Your capacitive current will be $I_\mathrm{c}=2\pi fCU$, where $f$ is your measurement frequency, $C$ is the capacitance, and $U$ is the applied ac voltage. You have to see how this current compares to the resistive current through your device.